# When using pandas.DataFrame.from_dict, values greater than 127 becomes -1 in the data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary, debugging

I converted the image into the pixel values using PIL and then tried to wrap the whole thing into the data frame using the following code:

```
pixelsDict = {
    'x':[],
    'y':[],
    'R':[],  
    'G':[],
    'B':[]
    }

for y in range(len(pixels)):
    for x in range(len(pixels[y])):
        r, g, b = pixels[y][x][0], pixels[y][x][1], pixels[y][x][2]
        pixelsDict['x'].append(x)
        pixelsDict['y'].append(y)
        pixelsDict['R'].append(r)
        pixelsDict['G'].append(g)
        pixelsDict['B'].append(b)
pixelsDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pixelsDict)
```

But, all the values in the 'R', 'B' and 'G' column of the pixelsDf that is greater than 127 becomes -1. As most of you have already figured it out, those values are supposed to be between 0 to 255.
I cannot figure out what's going on here, I tried looking up everywhere and could not get an answer.
I have attached the relevant images as well.

Relevant information:

pixels.shape
(2202, 1664, 3)

pixelsDict['R']
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, ...]

Comment: What is `pixels.dtype`? If it is `int8`, that is your problem, since `np.int8(255) == -1`.

Comment: Thanks, @nonDucor.
`int8` was the issue!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.